# How to place text completely below image

Tags: html, css

I have a quick question, when I try to style my image in this example, the text doesn't go down in its own line? How can I do that without adding many br's, is there a easier way to do this? I DO NOT WANT TO EDIT ON THE IMAGE STYLE (thats the whole point of this question)

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/3vy8p6fx/

How do I get the "Staff" to be its own line?

```
  <strong>History</strong><br />    
    <br />
    <strong>Mission</strong><br />
    <br />
    <strong>Leadership</strong>
    <div class="image123">
        <div class="imgContainer">
            <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/vujic/">
                <img src="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Vujic-150x150.jpg">

                </img>
            </a>
             <p align="center">
                 <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/">Jasmina Vujic</a>
                 <br>Principal Investigator
             </p>
         </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
            <a href="http://www.nuc.berkeley.edu/karl-van-bibber">
                <img style="Padding-left: 5%;" src="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/KarlVan-Resized-150x150.jpg">
                </img>
            </a>
             <p align="center">
                 <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/">Karl Van Bibber</a>
                 <br>Executive Director
             </p>
         </div>
        <div class="imgContainer">
            <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/vujic/">
                <img style="Padding-left: 5%;" src="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Bradley_M_Sherrill-150x150.png">
                </img>
            </a>
             <p align="center">
                 <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/">Bradley Sherill</a>
                 <br>Deputy Exec Director
             </p>
         </div>
         <div class="imgContainer">
            <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/vujic/">
                <img style="Padding-left: 5%;" src="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Vetter-150x150.jpg">
                </img>
            </a>
             <p align="center">
                 <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/">Kai Vetter</a>
                 <br>NNSA Liaison
             </p>
         </div>
         <div class="imgContainer">
            <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/vujic/">
                <img style="Padding-left: 5%;" src="http://npwg.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Leadership-Bethany-Goldblum.png">
                </img>
            </a>
             <p align="center">
                 <a href="http://nssc-test.berkeley.edu/leadership/">Bethany Goldblum</a>
                 <br>Associate Director
             </p>
         </div>

        </div>
             <br>
                 <b>Staff:</b>
```

css: 
.imgContainer

```
{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, simply adding the following will resolve your issue:

```
.image123 { overflow: auto }
```

That being said, I would refactor this a bit to use something like flexbox. I took the liberty to rework your fiddle a bit to reflect better semantics, and more organized styling.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3vy8p6fx/3/

---

*The following material was in response to the original code provided by the OP.*

This is because the image is positioned absolutely to the viewport, thus removed from the flow of the layout, overlapping the paragraph. Also, the image element is self-closing, thus `</img>` is not needed.

Furthermore, paragraphs are *already* block elements. So your inline styles are not needed. Remove *all* styles, and you'll have the effect you're desiring.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <img src="w3css.gif" />
        <p>This is a heading.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you *must* have the image positioned absolutely, at the top of the document, you can give the `<body>` itself some additional padding to push the contents (the `<p>` in this case) down further:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 150px;
            }
            img {
                top: 0; left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px; height: 140px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="w3css.gif" />
        <p>This is a heading.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My question is in general, how do I do this when I need the styles? Because I am trying to create images stacked next to each other, and I've done that successfully, but then my text which is supposed to a line of itself does not work unless I had many <br>'s, or if I do Padding-bottom/up, position, etc, but that makes the website unresponsive.

Comment: @user3827175 What effect are you trying to achieve? Can you mock up an example in Photoshop/Paint, and share here?

Comment: @JonathanSampson http://gyazo.com/f6c745c0cd17b8b1a999ffc8603120b3
Except I don't want to edit any of the image styles.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I have uploaded a better fiddle, 

https://jsfiddle.net/3vy8p6fx/

How can I get the Staff to be it's own line?

Comment: @user3827175 I really feel uneasy about the approach you're taking in general, since I don't know what you're ultimately trying to achieve, but you can give the body a greater `padding-top` to achieve this. See my answer above.

Comment: @user3827175 In that fiddle, you should use something like flex-box to lay out those elements. You can, however, simply add `.image123 { overflow: auto }` to achieve the new line.

Comment: @JonathanSampson all I wanted was the Staff to not be on the right hand side and come down to its own line, your padding-top technique does not work by the way, however, the overflow worked out perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user3827175 The `padding-top` approach works for the code you provided in the question; your fiddle is *different*. Both of these are not idea though for what you're attempting to achieve. What browser support are you aiming for?

Comment: @JonathanSampson, thanks for all of your help once again. In general though, why didn't the padding-top work for my fiddle? Is there something I am missing? I just want to understand, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3827175 Your fiddle doesn't deal with absolutely positioned images like your code here did; Further, your code here has the paragraph at the very top of the document, while your fiddle is dealing with a title element that follows paragraphs, images, and more. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0):

just change your

```
.imgContainer
        {
            float: left;
        }
```

TO

```
.imgContainer
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

**DEMO:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/3vy8p6fx/2/

NOTICE:

i changed some html syntax too, like:

instead of `<img ...></img>` i do `<img ... />`

break tags `<br>` to `<br/>`
...etc. look to my DEMO!